# SAS - Call execute

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have used `call execute` to call a macro to write the output file line by line but it has written only the last line in the output file.

```
%Macro INPS(ipdsn);
     filea = &ipdsn;
     %put MACRO:     ipdsn -->: &ipdsn;
     %put MACRO:     ipdsn -->: filea;
     newHostDSN = prxchange (re_iPat, -1, trim(&filea));
 do i=1 to f_count;
    set Var_Patterns(keep=Pat_Name Pat_Value) point=i nobs=f_count;
    re_vPat = cats('s/\$', Pat_Name, '(\.)?/', Pat_Value, '/i');
    newHostDSN = prxchange (re_vPat, -1, trim(newHostDSN));
 end;
 %Mend;
 data _null_;
     files   = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBB';
     f_count = countw(files);
     do i=1 to f_count;
         file = scan(files, i, ',');
         put 'DATA STEP: ipdsn -->: ' file;
         CALL EXECUTE (cats( '%INPS(', file, ');' ));
    end;
run;
```

output:

```
DATA STEP: ipdsn -->: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
MACRO:     ipdsn -->: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
MACRO:     ipdsn -->: filea
DATA STEP: ipdsn -->: BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
MACRO:     ipdsn -->: BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
MACRO:     ipdsn -->: filea
```

I want to store the data step value (file name) in a variable inside macro(filea) and use it for other validation in macro (newhostdsn and do). any idea how can i do this?

Comment: Please consider proposing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please details the `%mcro` macro.

Comment: input file:

AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB


do i=1 to f_count;
      found = 1;
      ipdsn = file;
      put 'ipdsn --B>:' ipdsn;
      CALL EXECUTE ('%INPS(ipdsn);');
      put 'ipdsn --A>:' ipdsn;
   end;
end;

%Macro INPS(ipdsn);

putlog 'ipdsn>' ipdsn;

%Mend;

Output is written as "BBBBBB" instead of A and B in sequence


BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

Comment: Please update the OP with *runnable* code that reproduces the issue.  I think you have a problem caused by the way you're using macro variables but it's hard to tell without code that actually works.  Write a complete data step, *not pseudocode*.

Comment: Thanks for the update - it's now clear where your confusion lies.

Comment: @Joe any idea how can i do it using call execute?

Answer (score 0):

It will execute immediately.

> **If an EXECUTE routine argument is a macro invocation or resolves to
> one, the macro executes immediately.** Execution of SAS statements
> generated by the execution of the macro will be delayed until after a
> step boundary. **SAS macro statements, including macro variable
> references, will execute immediately.**

[CALL EXECUTE documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/n1q1527d51eivsn1ob5hnz0yd1hx.htm#p1ocyy242ry4m2n15fa4w9fgm6xu)

Using your example:

```
data _null_;
    files   = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBB';
    f_count = countw(files);

    do i=1 to f_count;
        file = scan(files, i, ',');
        put 'DATA STEP: ipdsn -->: ' file;
        CALL EXECUTE (cats( '%INPS(', file, ');' ));
    end;

run;

%Macro INPS(ipdsn);
    %put MACRO:     ipdsn -->: &ipdsn;
%Mend;
```

Log Output:

```
DATA STEP: ipdsn -->: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
MACRO:     ipdsn -->: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
DATA STEP: ipdsn -->: BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
MACRO:     ipdsn -->: BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: input file:

AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB


do i=1 to f_count;
      found = 1;
      ipdsn = file;
      put 'ipdsn --B>:' ipdsn;
      CALL EXECUTE ('%INPS(ipdsn);');
      put 'ipdsn --A>:' ipdsn;
   end;
end;

%Macro INPS(ipdsn);

putlog 'ipdsn>' ipdsn;

%Mend;

Output is written as "BBBBBB" instead of A and B in sequence


BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

Comment: will the CALL EXECUTE be triggered at the EOF?

Comment: Your code that you posted is invalid. It will not execute correctly. I have added the corrected code to your this answer. Run it and see the results.

Comment: @StuSztukowski I am unsure that the `run` is appropriate here.  Or rather, it may be that it is appropriate, but it's at minimum missing from OP's example, and makes a huge difference...

Comment: Great point Joe. @samrat can you post a full reproducible example that can run on anyone's machine? Right now your code is unclear.

Comment: data f_i_pats;

  found = 0;
  do i=1 to f_count;
     if prxmatch(iPat_RE, trim(file)) > 0 then do;
        found = 1;
        iFTP_DSN = file;
        put 'iFTP_DSN--A>:' iFTP_DSN;
        CALL EXECUTE (cats('%IPATS(iFTP_DSN);'));
        put 'iFTP_DSN--z>:' iFTP_DSN;
     end;
  end;

Comment: %MACRO IPATS(iFTP_DSN);
   data _NULL_;
  
     tHost_DSN = prxchange (re_fix1, -1, trim(iHost_DSN));


     re_iPat = cats('s/¬', iPat, '$/', tHost_DSN, '/');
     newHostDSN = prxchange (re_iPat, -1, trim(iFTP_DSN));


    /* Now write the "GET" command */
     put  iFTP_DSN '+';
     put   newHostDSN;


     if last then do;
        put 'quit';
     end;
   run;
%MEND;                                /* End Macro                */

Comment: @StuSztukowski when i run the above code, only last records is being iterated.. can u pls advise whether i can write multiple records using CALL EXECUTE and Macro. or do i have to use any other approach

Comment: Please post your code to your original question. It is extremely difficult to copy and paste it here.

Comment: @StuSztukowski i have updated the original question.. can you please advise

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're not really understanding how SAS variables (and macro variables) work.

What `CALL EXECUTE` does is tells SAS to execute the code inside the `call execute` immediately *after* the data step completes.  Your example code contains data step lines, but they're not inside a data step - they're just executed inside open code.  Put them in a data step, and they'll execute fine.

```
%Macro INPS(ipdsn);
    data _null_;
     filea = "&ipdsn";
     %put MACRO:     ipdsn -->: &ipdsn;
     %put MACRO:     ipdsn -->: filea;
     newHostDSN = trim(filea);
     put newHostDSN=;
   run;
 %Mend;
 data _null_;
     files   = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBB';
     f_count = countw(files);
     do i=1 to f_count;
         file = scan(files, i, ',');
         put 'DATA STEP: ipdsn -->: ' file;
         CALL EXECUTE (cats( '%INPS(', file, ');' ));
    end;
run;
```

That puts the right value inside `newHostDSN`.

Now, there is something else important: the macro statements do execute "before" the run.  This is pretty important if your macro is more complicated.

See the following code.

```
%Macro namesbyage(name);
    proc sql;
      select age into :age
      from sashelp.class
      where name = "&name";
    quit;
    data _null_;
      set sashelp.class;
      where age = &age.;
      put age= name=;
    run;
 %Mend;
/* do not run this at first:
%symdel age;
*/
data _null_;
     set sashelp.class;
     call execute('%namesbyage('||name||')');
run;
```

Leaving the commented out part out, run it twice. The first time, it will work - except you'll get a whole bunch of warnings that `&age` does not exist - but it will correctly put various things to the log, age 12, age 13, et cetera.

The second time, it won't do the same thing!  You won't get the warning about `&age` not existing - but every single one of the executions *will be the same age*, the last age from the earlier run.

That is because, the first time, it's not converting `&age` the symbol into anything - it leaves it as `&age`, since there's no value yet.  That way, when the `proc sql; select into` creates `&age`, it works - because then it's resolved.

However, the second time, `&age` exists!  That means that when it creates the `call execute`, it is able to resolve `&age` right then - no need to wait.  So you get 15 (the present value of `&age` before anything runs) substituted in.  That's not what you want!

Now uncomment `%symdel age;` .  That deletes the age symbol, making every run like the first - it works, but with the warnings about `&age` not resolving.

How can you fix this?  Well, one way is to use that `%symdel` statement.  That deletes age, so you know for sure it won't be prematurely resolved.  That's not really the best way, but it works.

Better, is to use `%nrstr`, which "hides" age from the parser.

```
%Macro namesbyage(name);
    
    
    proc sql;
      select age into :age
      from sashelp.class
      where name = "&name";
    quit;
    
    
    data _null_;
      set sashelp.class;
      where age = %nrstr(&age);
      put age= name=;
    run;
%Mend;
```

Now, age is not resolved until later on - after the macro has been called by the `call execute`.

Third, you can do the same thing inside the `call execute`!

```
data _null_;
     set sashelp.class;
     call execute('%nrstr(%namesbyage('||name||'))');
run;
```

This would hide the whole macro from the `call execute` parser.  This is easiest in the scheme of things - everything happens later, at the expected time.

You also could use something other than `call execute` to execute your macros - for example, you could use my `select into` syntax to create a macro variable to do all of the executions.

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%namesbyage(',name,')') 
    into :namelist separated by ' '
    from sashelp.class;
quit;
&namelist.;
```

Here the `namelist` macro variable actually contains the text for all of the macro executions - so just running that macro variable in open code calls them all as if you'd typed them all out.  This has advantages (simultaneous execution) and disadvantages (limited to 60k characters in particular).  You could also write the calls out to a text file and `%include` that text file.

---

Why didn't your example fail?  Because it was using a *macro parameter* that wasn't a macro variable, that's why.  If `ipdsn` had existed as a separate macro variable, not a parameter, it would be resolved - and fail to work, which is *most likely* what you're seeing in your real example.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. Infact i have tried the code inside macro with data step, but still i m not getting the value on the variable

I have also tried the code which u provided..result is same.. Would you be able to help please?

DATA STEP: ipdsn -->: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
MACRO:     ipdsn -->: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
MACRO:     ipdsn -->: filea
DATA STEP: ipdsn -->: BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
MACRO:     ipdsn -->: BBBBBBBBBBBBBB

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, here.  What value is not where you expect?

Comment: i want the input record to be passed from data step inside macro variable (filea)

 when i print the variable, i m getting like this  "MACRO: ipdsn -->: filea" , instead of 

MACRO: ipdsn -->: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA and MACRO: ipdsn -->: BBBBBBBBBBBBB

Comment: That's not how it works, though, you can't say "macro variable = data step variable".  You *do* have the value in the parameter of your macro, which you can use however you want - you can't reference it by variable name, though.